# In JUnit 5, how to run code before all tests

Tags: java, junit, junit5

The `@BeforeAll` annotation marks a method to run before all tests in a *class*.

http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations

But is there a way to run some code before *all* tests, in all classes?

I want to ensure that tests use a certain set of database connections, and the global one-time setup of these connections must occur **before** running **any** tests.

Comment: Just for the record: in case you find one of the answers helpful enough - please consider accepting one of them at some point ;-)

Answer (score 167):

This is now possible in JUnit5 by creating a custom Extension, from which you can register a shutdown hook on the root test-context.

Your extension would look like this;

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL;

public class YourExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {

    private static boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            // Your "before all tests" startup logic goes here
            // The following line registers a callback hook when the root test context is shut down
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Your "after all tests" logic goes here
    }
}
```

Then, any tests classes where you need this executed at least once, can be annotated with:

```java
@ExtendWith({YourExtension.class})
```

When you use this extension on multiple classes, the startup and shutdown logic will only be invoked once.

Comment: If you need to execute this for every test class, then you could also use [automatic extension regristration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic) to register the extension using a ServiceLoader. Then you don't need to annotate every single test (with the risks that you might miss some).

Comment: in my case the `close` from `CloseableResource` wasn't called, but `afterAll` from `AfterAllCallback` was

Comment: FWIW I implemented this with Spring to setup test data using a DataSource bean, and it worked nicely; details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504238/278800. I couldn't have done it without your helpful answer, thanks!

Comment: I couldn't help myself and had to post a flamboyant "going a bit further" answer. Vote it up if you think it adds to the convo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450782/5957643

Comment: I [extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65897949/325868) the provided sample to be valid in parallel execution as well as the above mentioned automatic extension registration.

Comment: One unfortunate flaw with this approach: it is possible for other tests that don't share the extension to run between tests with the extension. Therefore, it may not be a suitable solution if the environment is shared in such a way that other tests running between break expectations

Comment: If you get some weird errors, don't be an idiot like me and make your extension class abstract.  Otherwise this works like a gem.

Comment: You should use `getOrComputeIfAbsent` to avoid use of static variable `started` and make it thread-safe.

Comment: Is this line necessary? "context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);

I dont see it used in the above example after setup?

Comment: How would I do this without needing to add the `@ExtendWith` annotation to every class?

Comment: You should use only `store` to store the state. The `started` variable is IMHO not necessary - just checking the store if it contains "any unique name" should be enough.

Answer (score 33):

The already provided answer from [@Philipp Gayret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556718/325868) has some problems when testing JUnit in **parallel** (i.e. `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true`).

Therefore I adapted the solution to:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public class BeforeAllTestsExtension extends BasicTestClass
        implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {

    /** Gate keeper to prevent multiple Threads within the same routine */
    private static final Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();
    /** volatile boolean to tell other threads, when unblocked, whether they should try attempt start-up.  Alternatively, could use AtomicBoolean. */
    private static volatile boolean started = false;
    
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(final ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        // lock the access so only one Thread has access to it
        LOCK.lock();
        try {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;
                // Your "before all tests" startup logic goes here
                // The following line registers a callback hook when the root test context is
                // shut down
                context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);

                // do your work - which might take some time - 
                // or just uses more time than the simple check of a boolean
            }
        } finally {
            // free the access
            LOCK.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Your "after all tests" logic goes here
    }
}
```

As mentioned below JUnit5 provides an automatic [Extension Registration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic). To do so add a in `src/test/resources/` a directory called `/META-INF/services` and add a file named `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension`. Add into this file the fully classified name of your class, e.g.

```
at.myPackage.BeforeAllTestsExtension
```

Next enable in the same Junit config file

```
junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true
```

With this the extension is attached automatically to all of your tests.

Comment: Works perfect! Hint: The extension class has to be public, like in this example

Comment: Should probably have `unlock` in a `finally` block and all the code in between `lock` and `unlock` in a `try`

Comment: @RyanMoser: Please correct/update it. Thx.

Comment: @LeO will do.  The queue is apparently full ATM, so I have to wait?  This is my first edit attempt lol

Comment: Does `started` have to be `volatile` when used inside a _lock_?

Comment: @rychu Just use `getOrComputeIfAbsent` to avoid multithreading issues.

Comment: you should @ResourceLock instead

Comment: The code works great but what is the use of this line in above example? "context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);"

Comment: Hm, where do I import BasicTestClass from?

Comment: @Zhenya: Just take it as example - you could remove it ;-)

Comment: @PramodYadav: Just copy-paste the original code and adapted it. Don't think I'm in charge to answer it "properly" ;-)

Comment: @SylvainLecoy: I looked up the @ResourceLock  - first of all it is mentioned as `Experimental`. On the other hand I have no clue how to apply this annotation properly. You are welcome to add an update my answer by adding some code snippet.

Comment: Can we just use "synchronized" instead of the lock logic?

Answer (score 6):

Extending on suggestion from @Philipp, here's a more complete code snippet:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL;    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public abstract class BaseSetupExtension
    implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {

  @Override
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    // We need to use a unique key here, across all usages of this particular extension.
    String uniqueKey = this.getClass().getName();
    Object value = context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).get(uniqueKey);
    if (value == null) {
      // First test container invocation.
      context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put(uniqueKey, this);
      setup();
    }
  }

  // Callback that is invoked <em>exactly once</em> 
  // before the start of <em>all</em> test containers.
  abstract void setup();

  // Callback that is invoked <em>exactly once</em> 
  // after the end of <em>all</em> test containers.
  // Inherited from {@code CloseableResource}
  public abstract void close() throws Throwable;
}
```

How to use:

```
public class DemoSetupExtension extends BaseSetupExtension {
  @Override
  void setup() {}

  @Override
  public void close() throws Throwable {}
}  

@ExtendWith(DemoSetupExtension.class)
public class TestOne {
   @BeforeAll
   public void beforeAllTestOne { ... }

   @Test
   public void testOne { ... }
}

@ExtendWith(DemoSetupExtension.class)
public class TestTwo {
   @BeforeAll
   public void beforeAllTestTwo { ... }

   @Test
   public void testTwo { ... }
}
```

Test execution order will be:

```
  DemoSetupExtension.setup (*)
  TestOne.beforeAllTestOne
  TestOne.testOne
  TestOne.afterAllTestOne
  TestTwo.beforeAllTestTwo
  TestTwo.testTwo
  TestTwo.afterAllTestTwo
  DemoSetupExtension.close (*)
```

...this will be true regardless if you choose to run a single @Test (e.g.
TestOne.testOne), or an entire test class (TestOne), or multiple / all tests.

Comment: Worked first time, when combined with the information on [auto-registering extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic).

Comment: how/why does it close only once? probably: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-keeping-state

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a mean to do that.

I would simply make sure that all code for @BeforeAll calls a certain singleton to make that init work (probably in a lazy way to avoid repetition).

Probably not convenient ... the only other option I see: I assume your tests run within a specific JVM job. You *could* hook an *[agent](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/)* into that JVM run, that does that init work for you.

Beyond that: both suggestions sounds somehow like a hack to me. The **real** answer in my eyes: step back, and carefully examine your environment on its dependencies. And then find a way to **prepare** your environment in a way that your tests come up and the "right thing" happens automatically. In other words: consider looking into the architecture that bought you this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Above advises do **not** work for me, so I solved this problem like this:

Add to your Base abstract class (I mean abstract class where you initialize your driver in *setUpDriver()* method) this part of code:

```
private static boolean started = false;
static{
    if (!started) {
        started = true;
        try {
            setUpDriver();  //method where you initialize your driver
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And now, if your test classes will **extends** from Base abstract class -> *setUpDriver()* method will be executed before first @Test only **ONE** time per project run.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my POC refinement to the very good answer from [@Phillip Gayret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066946/philipp-gayret), following in [@Mihnea Giurgea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14296808/mihnea-giurgea)'s footsteps.

My sub-question: ***How to access that shared singleton resource?*** (Perhaps you are also wondering this...)

***Sidebar:*** During my experimentation, I discovered that using multiple `@ExtendWith(...)` seems to nest properly. Even so, I remember it not working that way at some point in my fumbling, so you should ***make sure your usage case(s) are workings rightly [sic].***

Because you are probably in a rush, *the dessert comes first:* Here is the output of running "all tests within the folder":

```
NestedSingleton::beforeAll (setting resource)
Singleton::Start-Once
Base::beforeAll
Colors::blue - resource=Something nice to share!
Colors::gold - resource=Something nice to share!
Base::afterAll
Base::beforeAll
Numbers::one - resource=Something nice to share!
Numbers::tre - resource=Something nice to share!
Numbers::two - resource=Something nice to share!
Base::afterAll
Singleton::Finish-Once
NestedSingleton::close (clearing resource)
```

Of course, just running a single test class gives:

```
NestedSingleton::beforeAll (setting resource)
Singleton::Start-Once
Base::beforeAll
Numbers::one - resource=Something nice to share!
Numbers::tre - resource=Something nice to share!
Numbers::two - resource=Something nice to share!
Base::afterAll
Singleton::Finish-Once
NestedSingleton::close (clearing resource)
```

And a specific test, as can now be expected:

```
NestedSingleton::beforeAll (setting resource)
Singleton::Start-Once
Base::beforeAll
Colors::gold - resource=Something nice to share!
Base::afterAll
Singleton::Finish-Once
NestedSingleton::close (clearing resource)
```

Still with me? Then you might enjoy seeing the actual code...

```java
======================================================
junitsingletonresource/Base.java
======================================================
package junitsingletonresource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith({Singleton.class})
public abstract class Base extends BaseNestedSingleton
{
    @BeforeAll public static void beforeAll() { System.out.println("Base::beforeAll"); }
    @AfterAll  public static void afterAll () { System.out.println("Base::afterAll" ); }
}

======================================================
junitsingletonresource/Colors.java
======================================================
package junitsingletonresource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Colors extends Base
{
    @Test public void blue() { System.out.println("Colors::blue - resource=" + getResource()); }
    @Test public void gold() { System.out.println("Colors::gold - resource=" + getResource()); }
}

======================================================
junitsingletonresource/Numbers.java
======================================================
package junitsingletonresource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Numbers extends Base
{
   @Test public void one() { System.out.println("Numbers::one - resource=" + getResource()); }
   @Test public void two() { System.out.println("Numbers::two - resource=" + getResource()); }
   @Test public void tre() { System.out.println("Numbers::tre - resource=" + getResource()); }
}

======================================================
junitsingletonresource/BaseNestedSingleton.java
======================================================
package junitsingletonresource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL;

/**
 * My riff on Phillip Gayret's solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556718/5957643
 */
@ExtendWith({BaseNestedSingleton.NestedSingleton.class})
public abstract class BaseNestedSingleton
{
    protected String getResource() { return NestedSingleton.getResource(); }

    static /*pkg*/ class NestedSingleton implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource
    {
        private static boolean initialized = false;
        private static String  resource    = "Tests should never see this value (e.g. could be null)";

        private static String getResource() { return resource; }

        @Override
        public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context)
        {
            if (!initialized) {
                initialized = true;

                // The following line registers a callback hook when the root test context is shut down

                context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), this);

                // Your "before all tests" startup logic goes here, e.g. making connections,
                // loading in-memory DB, waiting for external resources to "warm up", etc.

                System.out.println("NestedSingleton::beforeAll (setting resource)");
                resource    = "Something nice to share!";
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            if (!initialized) { throw new RuntimeException("Oops - this should never happen"); }

            // Cleanup the resource if needed, e.g. flush files, gracefully end connections, bury any corpses, etc.

            System.out.println("NestedSingleton::close (clearing resource)");
            resource = null;
        }
    }
}

======================================================
junitsingletonresource/Singleton.java
======================================================
package junitsingletonresource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL;

/**
 * This is pretty much what Phillip Gayret provided, but with some printing for traceability
 */
public class Singleton implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource
{
    private static boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context)
    {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            System.out.println("Singleton::Start-Once");
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() { System.out.println("Singleton::Finish-Once"); }
}
```