# JUnit 5 - Providing setUp and tearDown for an entire Test Suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

My requirement is to have some initialization done for a set of tests and clear it off once all the tests are complete. These tests spin over a few test classes as they are not closely related, but require a common initialization.

I am using `@SelectClasses` to form the suite and trying to make use of `@ExtendWith` using a custom extension that should handle the pre and post processing. This does not work and I am unsure if an appropriate solution exists in JUnit. Sharing the sample code of what was already attempted.

**Suite:**

```
@SelectClasses({FirstTest.class, SecondTest.class})
@ExtendWith(SuiteExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("test suite")
public class SuiteClass {
}
```

**Extension:**

```
public class SuiteExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterAll");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("beforeAll");
    }
}
```

**Test Class 1:**

```
public class FirstTest {

    @Test
    void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1");
    }
}
```

**Test Class 2:**

```
public class SecondTest {

    @Test
    void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
test1
test2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
beforeAll
test1
test2
afterAll
```

Comment: something similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282798/in-junit-5-how-to-run-code-before-all-tests

Answer (score 6):

Combining `@RunWith` (from JUnit 4) and `@ExtendWith` (from JUnit Jupiter) is not supported: those are extension mechanisms from two different frameworks.

Technically speaking, your `SuiteClass` is a JUnit 4 test class. Thus JUnit Jupiter will not register or execute any extensions for it.

With regard to *suites* in JUnit 5, we (the JUnit Team) have plans to provide first-class support for suites that do not require a JUnit 4 *Runner* (i.e., `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`). See all [GitHub issues labeled with "suites"](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3A%22theme%3A%20suites%22) for details. Feel free to watch and/or comment on any of those issues.

In the interim, I believe the closest one could come to implementing "before and after suite" support in JUnit Jupiter would be to implement a custom extension that implements `BeforeAllCallback` and `AfterAllCallback`. That extension would need to track whether it has already been invoked by storing a flag in the *root* `ExtensionContext` `Store` (as a `BeforeAllCallback`), so that it only executes *once* before the "suite". Similarly, it would need to count the number of classes it is executed for and track that in the *root* `Store`. This would serve as a `Stack` or `CountDownLatch`. As an `AfterAllCallback`, the extension would need to decrement the global counter and only *execute* once all test classes have completed.

You'd obviously need to ensure that your suite extension is registered for each test class that belongs to the suite. Perhaps a custom composed annotation would simplify matters for you there.

Now, admittedly, I just *implemented* that in my head but have not yet actually coded such a "suite" extension. So if you actually implement it, I'd be interested in hearing about your experience and possibly seeing your code. ;-)

Cheers,

Sam (core committer for JUnit 5)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Sam. I will try the mentioned and share the solution I come up with.

Comment: Just implemented this solution, where I start up a WireMock server before all integration tests. Would be so much easier if there would be a `BeforeTestSuiteCallback` and `AfterTestSuiteCallback`

Comment: FWIW I implemented this with Spring and it worked nicely, details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504238/278800. Thanks for your helpful answer!