# How to initialize a static resource in the base class for all tests in the project using JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

Given the following code:

```java
    public abstract class Base {

      @BeforeAll
      public static void beforeAll() {
        System.out.println("Base::beforeAll");
      }

      @AfterAll
      public static void afterAll() {
        System.out.println("Base::afterAll");
      }
    }

    public class First extends Base {

      @Test
      public void test() {
        System.out.println("First::test");
      }
    }

    public class Second extends Base {

      @Test
      public void test() {
        System.out.println("Second::test");
      }
    }
```

I would like to have the following execution model:

```
    Base::beforeAll
    First::test
    Second::test
    Base::afterAll
```

Instead, I get this:

```
    Base::beforeAll
    First::test
    Base::afterAll

    Base::beforeAll
    Second::test
    Base::afterAll
```

I'm aware of `BeforeAllCallback` and `AfterAllCallback`, but they simply provide the callback hooks for lifecycle annotations like `BeforeAll` and `AfterAll`.

Is there any way you can safely run a setup method in the base class before running **all** tests in the project and then run some tear down method after running **all** the test methods in the entire project?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [In JUnit 5, how to run code before all tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282798/in-junit-5-how-to-run-code-before-all-tests)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use the combination of `BeforeCallback` and `ExecutionContext` in order to achieve this kind of behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556718/11692167