# Is there a way to get event in spring (+junit) fired after all tests classes?

Tags: spring, testing, junit, spring-test

I use spring 5 + junit 5. And I have two classes - BarIT and FooIT.

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ModuleContextConfig.class)
public class FooIT {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}

@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ModuleContextConfig.class)
public class BarIT {

    @Test
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("Bar");
    }
}
```

This is my suite:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SelectClasses({
    FooIT.class,
    BarIT.class
})
@IncludeClassNamePatterns(".*IT$")
public class SuiteIT {

}
```

I want to get event when *tests in two classes have been executed*, I mean event after  FooIT.foo() and BarIT.bar(), however, I can't do that. I hoped to get ContextClosedEvent but it is not fired:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Event:" + event.toString());
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Event:org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent..
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.PrepareTestInstanceEvent..
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.BeforeTestMethodEvent..
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.BeforeTestExecutionEvent..
Foo
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.AfterTestExecutionEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.AfterTestMethodEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.AfterTestClassEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.BeforeTestClassEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.PrepareTestInstanceEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.BeforeTestMethodEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.BeforeTestExecutionEvent...
Bar
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.AfterTestExecutionEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.AfterTestMethodEvent...
Event:org.springframework.test.context.event.AfterTestClassEvent..
```

Could anyone say how to do it, if it is possible.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070019/1092818) will help?

Comment: @crizzis Thank you for your comment. I know, that there junit extensions, but I try to find a way to do it only using spring and only with one extension - `@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})`.

Comment: In such case, you could try using a custom [`TestExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) and keeping track which test classes have finished executing in `afterTestClass()`. you can override the default listener chain using `@TestExecutionListeners`, just make sure to include all the default listeners your tests need. It will take similar effort to a JUnit extension, though

Comment: @crizzis Yes, I thought about it. But to get the point after all classes I can only if I know how many tests junit has (after that I only count tests and find the remainder). But I didn't find a way to get test count from junit....

Comment: Not sure I follow. The suite has a fixed list of included test classes. Just hardcode the same list in the listener, and tick off the classes from the list when `afterTestClass()` gets called. Once the list is empty, you'll know that the last test from the suite finished executing. With some extra effort, you could even read the list off `@SelectClasses`, since it has runtime retention

Comment: @crizzis This doesn't work, if you have `@Ignore` `@Tag` etc. Number of test can be taken only from junit.

Comment: ...and that's precisely the reason why a JUnit extension is better suited for the job. With the constraint that only `SpringExtension` can be used, only a solution with limited usability can be reached. Note also that the original approach with `ContextClosedEvent` wouldn't work with `@DirtiesContext`, for example, because closing the context is not tantamount to having run all tests